# Maven: import multimodule projects into Eclipse when subprojects have same name

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have 2 multi-module projects. Both projects share nothing and have nothing in common.

```
PrjA (groupId=PrjA, artifactId=PrjA)
  Base (package=PrjA.Base, groupId=PrjA, artifactId=Base)
  Foo  (package=PrjA.Foo,  groupId=PrjA, artifactId=Foo)



PrjB (groupId=PrjB, artifactId=PrjB)
  Base (package=PrjB.Base, groupId=PrjB, artifactId=Base)
  Bar  (package=PrjB.Bar,  groupId=PrjB, artifactId=Bar)
```

Both projects are fine if I build them with mvn.

PrjA.Base is not equal to PrjB.Base - it is just the same name because both projects have basics inside of it.

But now I need to import them into Eclipse. Import the 1st project works fine.
But if I try to import the 2nd one then Base is a problem.

```
Project Base already exists
Add a version or custom suffix using "Name template" in "Advanced"
```

I see that the artifact Base is the same but the groupId is different.

Is there a requirement to have artifactId unique in Eclipse?

Comment: If you import a Maven project there you have a entry on the screen "Advanced". Click on the arrow and see there is an entry "Name template" and there is the drop down list which shows the different options for the names in Eclipse. The entry "[groupId].[artifactId]" is the one you should use...and afterwards import the project..and it should be done.

Comment: Thanks - that worked. Is there also a way to avoid having the project files in multiple ways?

`PrjA.PrjA - Base - src - main - java - ...`
and then also 
 `PrjA - PrjA.Base - src/main/java - PrjA.Base
`

It all points to the same file but in different views.
`

Comment: To be honest I don't understand your question?

Comment: Sorry - I not native engish speaking. In my new imported project I see multiple sub-trees - as I tried to show above. The nodes of the subtrees have different names but show the same content (leave is the file). I would like to have only ONE path to a file.

Answer (score 4):

When you are importing a Maven project in Eclipse, with the same name of other project that is already in your workspace, you need to give it a "Name template".

[image: Setup screen]